# Geometric intuition behind pseudo-distances

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, arc-length, rough-path-theory

Could somebody please offer some intuition into how pseudo-distances work?

Something like what the geometric interpretation is, and how they differ from distances, would be appreciated.

**Background**: I am currently studying the so-called $p$-variation, which is defined as follows:

$$ \| X\|_{p, [0,T]}:=\sup_{ D \subset [0,T] }{\left( \sum^{|D|}_{j=1} | X_{t_j} - X_{t_{j-1}}|^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}}$$,

where $ X_{(\cdot)}: [0,T] \to V $ is continuous, $T$ is a real number, $V$ is a Banach space, $|\cdot|$ is the norm on $ V$, and $ D$ is a partition of $[0,T]$. Since the 1-variation coincides with the definition of arc-length, the $p$-variation is a generalisation of arc-length. Defining $ \mathcal{V}^p([0,T], V)$ as the space of $V$-valued paths defined on $[0,T]$ of finite $p$-variation, it turns out that $\|\cdot\|_{p,J}$ defines a semi-norm on $ \mathcal{V}^p([0,T], V)$, which hence induces a pseudo-distance on this space ($\|\cdot\|_{\mathcal{V}^p([0,T], V)} := \|\cdot\|_{p,J} + \|\cdot\|_{\infty,J}$ defines a norm, which induces a distance on $ \mathcal{V}^p([0,T], V)$ ). It would be interesting to understand the geometric intuition of what semi-norms are, to better understand the geometric intuition of two paths being close in $p$-variation pseudo-distance.

Comment: Some authors also allow pseudo-distances to take infinite values (besides zero value for different points).

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically speaking, a semi-norm is the same as a usual norm, but there may be points that are distinct but have distance $0$.

The $p$-variation semi-norm is probably not the first semi-norm that you have encountered. The usual construction of the Lebesgue spaces is defining the set

$$ \mathcal{L}^p := \{ f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: f ~ \text{measurable}, \int_{\Omega} \vert f \vert^p d \mu < \infty \} $$

equipped with the semi-norm

$$ \Vert f \Vert_{p} = \left( \int_{\Omega} \vert f \vert^p d \mu\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$

However, this of course means that if two measurable functions are equal $\mu$-a.s., then their difference has norm $0$. In order to solve this one passes to $\mathcal{L}^p / \ker( \Vert \cdot \Vert_p )$ on which $\Vert \cdot \Vert_p$ is a bona fide norm.

For the $p$-variation semi-norm we have $\Vert \alpha \Vert_p = 0$ for every constant $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Hence the $p$-variation cannot distinguish constants and thus the distance between any two functions which differ only by a constant is $0$. To solve this one adds the term $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{\infty}$, which can distinguish constant functions from $0$.

Comment: I like this answer. See my question about a problem that arises with the $p$-variation when it comes to saying that a function is Lipschitz on points, which does not imply the function is Lip. (even locally) on paths with the $p$-variation semi-norm. This is exactly because two paths that differ by a constant yield constant paths when their difference is considered, whose $p$-variation is zero. When adding the sup-norm to get the $p$-variation norm, it can be proven that a function that is Lip. on points is Lip. on paths, with a Lip. constant that depends on the the $p$-variation of the paths

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268454/lipschitz-does-not-bound-increments-by-1-variation/4268928#4268928